# Update datatable field based on the value exist in another datatable in Asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, linq-to-dataset

Hi I have two datatable

## table

```
id  isfav
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   0
5   0
```

## favtable

```
id 
2
3
```

So I want to Update the `table1` field `isFav` to 1 if the ids exist in `FavTable`.

Can anybody help me on this

Comment: write some code first

Comment: Is this `Database` table or c# `datatable` ?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL...

```
UPDATE table SET isfav = 1 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM favtable WHERE favtable.id = table.id)
```

In Linq to SQL...

```
//Create DataContext first

foreach (var rec in from a in dc.table
                    join b in dc.favtable on a.id equals b.id
                    select a)
{
     a.isfav = true;
}

dc.SubmitChanges();
```

...or (more efficient)...

```
dc.ExecuteCommand("UPDATE table SET isfav = 1 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM favtable WHERE favtable.id = table.id)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since in the comments it was mentioned it is `DataTable`, you could use `Join` between these tables as below and update the field.

```
table1.AsEnumerable()
      .Join( table2.AsEnumerable(),
            t1 => t1.Field<int>("id"),
            t2 => t2.Field<int>("id"),
            (t1, t2) => new { t1 })
      .ToList()
      .ForEach(o => o.t1["isfav"] = 1);
```

Check this [`working code`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fKSyul)